# Failing to get the desired results for a RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a SELECT, but failing to get the desired result. I've got a JOIN between four tables (actually, there are more but the rest is mostly to show the actual name instead of product and company id values).

```
Product
- id_product
- model
- id_origin
- availability
- product_category
- id_chipset
- id_producttype

Stock
- id_product
- id_company
- stock_quantity
- on_the_way
- date_stock

Items
- id_order
- id_sell_out
- quantity
- price
- id_product

Orders
- id_sell_out
- date
- NF
- id_client
- id_company
```

What I need: A view containing a product column (Product.id_product), stock quantity (Stock.on_the_way and Stock.date_stock) and Sales (Items.quantity) of all items that were EITHER sold OR are in stock. This is my current script:

```sql
SELECT  Product.model AS Chipset,
    SUM(items.quantity) AS Sales,
    Stock.stock_quantity AS 'Stock', 
    Stock.on_the_way AS 'On the Way', 
    WEEKOFYEAR(orders.date) AS 'Date'
FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN Items ON Orders.id_sell_out = Items.id_sell_out
    INNER JOIN Product ON Items.id_product = Product.id_product
    RIGHT JOIN Stock ON Product.id_product = Stock.id_product AND Orders.id_company = Stock.id_company
GROUP BY Stock.id_company, Product.model, WEEKOFYEAR(orders.date), Stock.stock_quantity, Stock.on_the_way
ORDER BY Stock.id_company, Product.model;
```

What I'm getting are just the rows for products that were BOTH sold AND are in stock. By using RIGHT JOIN with the stock table (instead of INNER JOIN), shouldn't I get all the entries from stock plus the intersection with the rest of the JOIN?

How to fix this code to get the desired results?

Answer (score 2):

`RIGHT JOIN` is notably counter-intuitive. I would rewrite you query to use `LEFT JOIN`s instead. You can start from the `Product` table, then bring in `Stock`, and then `left join` on `Item` and `Order`.

```
SELECT  
    p.model AS Chipset,
    SUM(i.quantity) AS Sales,
    s.stock_quantity AS 'Stock', 
    s.on_the_way AS 'On the Way', 
    WEEKOFYEAR(p.date) AS 'Date'
FROM 
    Product p
    INNER JOIN Stock s 
        ON p.id_product = s.id_product
    LEFT JOIN Items i
        ON i.id_product = p.id_product 
    LEFT JOIN Orders o
        ON  o.id_company = s.id_company
        AND o.id_sell_out = i.id_sell_out
GROUP BY 
    s.id_company, 
    p.model, 
    WEEKOFYEAR(o.date), 
    s.stock_quantity, 
    s.on_the_way
ORDER BY s.id_company, p.model;
```

Note: table aliases make the queries shorter and easier to understand. I modified your query accordingly.

Comment: *"Note: table aliases make the queries shorter and easier to understand"*  Maybe  what if you need to alias `Stock` and `StockPart` with short aliases .. Also the alias is visible in the `EXPLAIN` which means you need to backtracking the alias back into the query which makes it a bit more harder., Plus when reading the SELECT / WHERE / GROUP BY and so on clauses you directly know table where those columns are without searching imagine if you would need to search in a SQL query which is a few A4 pages long. i rather write out the table name fully but matter off opinions and or taste i geuss..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: good point about the EXPLAIN plan... and also table aliases need meaningful (not things like a, b, c...). In my opinion, the longer table names get (or when schema prefix are used), the more useful aliases are.

Comment: *"also table aliases need meaningful (not things like a, b, c...). In my opinion, the longer table names get (or when schema prefix are used), the more useful aliases are."* indeed if somebody is worried about lots off typing buy or use a open source SQL IDE which supports autocomplete, problem solved..

Comment: Your query is returning the same entries as mine. Filtering the table to show just one company for this week the Stock table has 7 entries, the INNER JOIN for items and Orders has 3 entires (one of which is also in the stock). So, this query should return me 9 entries. But it is only returning me 1 (the one that's present in both tables).

Comment: @rcps: as it is, the query will generate one record for each `product` record that is available in `Stock`. If you also want products that are not in stock, then you can change `INNER JOIN Stock s` to `LEFT JOIN Stock s`.